# Should setup.py install modify the registry?

Tags: python, registry, setuptools

I have a python package that provides a file format, and a tool to open it.

Is it reasonable for `python setup.py install` to add the appropriate keys to the windows registry to register the file extension as openable by the program?

And does `setuptools` already provide a way to do this?

Comment: [A github search](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=winreg+filename%3Asetup.py&type=Code&ref=searchresults) that find code that does this